# wp-cron.php not being triggered by wp_remote_post in spawn_cron()

Tags: wp-cron

I am trying to debug failing publication of scheduled posts. On a completely new wordpress installation, (using the default docker image), scheduled posts fail to get published when the correct time passes. 
I have enabled full php errors logging, and I have followed the steps that wp_cron takes (logging at each step). 
I see that in the function spawn_cron() , it arrives at the end, where it tells it to do wp_remote_post (passing the url https://mysite/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=A_TIMESTAMP_HERE ) .
This does not return an error, but a (serialised here for easier logging) result:

```
a:5:{s:7:"headers";a:0:{}s:4:"body";s:0:"";s:8:"response";a:2:{s:4:"code";b:0;s:7:"message";b:0;}s:7:"cookies";a:0:{}s:13:"http_response";N;}
```

I have added logging to the wp-cron.php, but it never gets triggered. 
Any idea what could be causing the wp_remote_post not to actually trigger the wp-cron.php ?

Comment: If you are logging that at the source of the call in `php` it should return an array or instance of `WP_Error` not a serialized string. With that said, the reason that the serialized array has empty/false/null values is because the request is issued as a non-blocking request meaning WP does not wait for a response on that call before returning from `spawn_cron`. See `wp-includes/class-http.php:L423`. Not exactly an answer but hopefully that provides some context. Perhaps try issuing your own `wp_remote_post` but in a blocking configuration to start.

Comment: Ah, bad explanation from my part: I am the one serialising it, in order to log it. It doesn't get returned serialised. Thanks for the clarification. I can see now why the reply is empty. As a test I will modify the wp_remote_post to a non blocking and see if I get a reply there. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: And that gave me a useful message back:  O:8:"WP_Error":2:{s:6:"errors";a:1:{s:19:"http_request_failed";a:1:{i:0;s:58:"cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 1000 milliseconds";}}s:10:"error_data";a:0:{}}"
Now I know where to look next. cURL. Thanks again

Comment: It's quite common for some hosting setups to not allow "loopback connections" (basically, connections back to the same server). I'd suggest contacting your host for assitance.

Comment: @JacobPeattie that's a very good point one I often overlook running my own servers where we don't encounter that. I wonder though, being that this is ran in a Docker container, surely this is not on shared host so maybe server config gone astray? As a work around I suggest defining `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` constant e.g. `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` in `wp-config.php` so that the issuing request (whoever made the request externally to the site) gets converted into transparent `GET` request-redirect. That should solve the issue.

Comment: Indeed, setting ALTERNATE_WP_CRON to true solved the issue in my case. Thanks